# Pyinstaller Spacy FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ...\\dist\\app\\thinc\\backends\\_custom_kernels.cu

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spacy

I get this custom_kernel.cu not found when I try to run my .exe file.
I'm using Python3.9.4, Pyinstaller4.2, Thinc8.0.3, and Spacy3.0.6.

I tried 2 solutions :

One with a hook :

```
# HOOK FILE FOR SPACY
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all, collect_data_files, copy_metadata

# ----------------------------- SPACY -----------------------------
data = collect_all('spacy')

datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]

# ----------------------------- THINC -----------------------------
data = collect_all('thinc')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- CYMEM -----------------------------
data = collect_all('cymem')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- PRESHED -----------------------------
data = collect_all('preshed')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- BLIS -----------------------------
data = collect_all('blis')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- OTHER -----------------------------
hiddenimports += ['srsly.msgpack.util']


# ----------------------------- EN CORE WEB MD -----------------------------
datas = collect_data_files("en_core_web_md")
datas.extend(copy_metadata("en_core_web_md"))
```

And another one with a BIG spec file (not recommended) :

```
import PyInstaller
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
import sys ; sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)

datas = []
datas.extend(PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files('spacy.lang', include_py_files = True))
datas.extend(PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files('thinc'))

datas = collect_data_files("en_core_web_md")

block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
     pathex=['C:\\Users\\appNew'],
     binaries=[],
     datas=datas,
     hiddenimports = [
        'spacy.kb',
        'spacy.lexeme',
        'spacy.matcher._schemas',
        'spacy.morphology',
        'spacy.parts_of_speech',
        'spacy.syntax._beam_utils',
        'spacy.syntax._parser_model',
        'spacy.syntax.arc_eager',
        'spacy.syntax.ner',
        'spacy.syntax.nn_parser',
        'spacy.syntax.stateclass',
        'spacy.syntax.transition_system',
        'spacy.tokens._retokenize',
        'spacy.tokens.morphanalysis',
        'spacy.tokens.underscore',
        'spacy.tokens._dict_proxies',

        'spacy._align',

        'blis',
        'blis.py',

        'cymem',
        'cymem.cymem',

        'murmurhash',
        'murmurhash.mrmr',

        'preshed.maps',

        'srsly.msgpack.util',

        'thinc.extra.search',
        'thinc.linalg',
        'thinc.neural._aligned_alloc',
        'thinc.neural._custom_kernels',
        'thinc.backends.linalg', 

        'sklearn.utils._cython_blas',
        'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs',
        'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree',
        'sklearn.tree._utils'
    ],
     hookspath=[],
     runtime_hooks=[],
     excludes=[],
     win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
     win_private_assemblies=False,
     cipher=block_cipher,
     noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
 a.scripts,
 [],
 exclude_binaries=True,
 name='app',
 debug=False,
 bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
 strip=False,
 upx=True,
 console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
       a.binaries,
       a.zipfiles,
       a.datas,
       strip=False,
       upx=True,
       upx_exclude=[],
       name='app')
```

Unfortunately both of these solutions didn't work.
Another solution would be to use an older version of Spacy, and En_core_md but in the long run this woulnd be great...

Answer (score 0):

Replacing '=' by '+=' in 'datas = collect_data_files("en_core_web_md")' seemed to have solved the problème (I know have a custom_kernel.cu file YAY!)